# Excel Custom Ribbon Auto-placement Before Home Tab?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, ribbon, regedit

I have created a custom ribbon for excel, and I was recently toying with Combo boxes & drop downs, and I accidentally uploaded the XML before I added subroutines in the VBA modules to account for "getItemID", "getItemLabel"...etc. specific to combo boxes. And so when I opened a new instance of excel, it gave me a debug message and for some strange reason it placed my custom ribbon before the home tab.

```
<tab id="RealEstateTab" label="Real Estate" insertAfterMso="TabView">
```

It doesn't matter what I type in this line of the XML, it never changes from acting like insertBeforeMso="TabHome"

I have a feeling it may be connected to the registry system settings for excel because when I open this custom ribbon on someone else's computer, it places the ribbon after the View Tab just like it should.

Comment: I have this same issue, even if I create a new workbook and a new custom tab in it: it is always placed before the Home tab. What version of Excel do you have? What OS? Does the other computer have the same version of each? I didn't get any errors when I first loaded my custom ribbon, so I think that is unrelated.

Comment: It has happened to me twice, once in office 2010, and this post is more recently on office 2013. But the probably randomly fixed itself. I'm still researching the issue though for future consideration

Comment: Do you have any other custom ribbon tabs? I do (my company installs them by default), and hiding off made my own custom tab move... though it's still not in the correct spot, and it moves back to the beginning the next time I open the file.